# addClass just for specific element without specific class or ID

Tags: jquery, html

How's goin' on bros ?

I have code that want to add a class to the element when user scrolls the page to the element position and I use this code :

```
  $(window).on('scroll',function(){
    Scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(Scroll >= $('img').position().top)
        $('img').addClass('rotate');
  });
```

And my html code is this :

```
<div class="some-class">
  <img src="http://blog.majidkn.com/wp-content/themes/majidkn2/images/mkn.png" class="feature-size">
</div>

<div class="some-class">
  <img src="http://blog.majidkn.com/wp-content/themes/majidkn2/images/mkn.png" class="feature-size">
</div>

<div class="some-class">
  <img src="http://blog.majidkn.com/wp-content/themes/majidkn2/images/mkn.png" class="feature-size">
</div>
```

Now, when I run the code, the `rotate` class applies to all the `img` tags. but I wanna add the `rotate` class just to the element that have the conditions that I said in my js `if` sentence !

What can I do now about it ? you can also see the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/majid1889/r4h2sdvb/) !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop into all the `img` and use `$(this)` to add class

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    Scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('img').each(function(){
    if(Scroll >= $(this).position().top)
        $(this).addClass('rotate');


      });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery's `filter` to get only the image tags that suits your requirement, like:

```
Scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
$('img').filter(function(index, el) {
    return Scroll >= el.position.top();
}).addClass('rotate');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) But I think it didn't work for me :-?? Can u please explain it more ?

Answer (score 0):

replace your if statement with this

```
$('img').each(function(index) {
 if(Scroll >= $(this).position().top)
    $(this).addClass('rotate');
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  Scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  $('img').each(function() {
    if (Scroll >= $(this).position().top)
      $(this).addClass('rotate');
  })


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some-class">
  <img src="http://blog.majidkn.com/wp-content/themes/majidkn2/images/mkn.png" class="feature-size">
</div>

<div class="some-class">
  <img src="http://blog.majidkn.com/wp-content/themes/majidkn2/images/mkn.png" class="feature-size">
</div>

<div class="some-class">
  <img src="http://blog.majidkn.com/wp-content/themes/majidkn2/images/mkn.png" class="feature-size">
</div>
```

Iterate through each image then use `this` context to tell the current image